# Multi-project Play framework applications in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

I’m using IntelliJ to develop a Play application. The application has several maven dependencies developed in house, some of them being marked “SNAPSHOT" meaning I want to see changes made in them immediately.

Now. When I make changes to the SNAPSHOT dependencies in IntelliJ, my Play Application doesn’t pick them up undil I build and install the modified artifacts (using maven) and trigger an SBT-build of the Play project. Otherwise the application doesn’t see my changes.

Is there any way for my Play application to resolve dependencies locally, without me having to do an install and build every time I modify one of the maven projects?

Cheers,
- hugi

PS: For those familiar with the Eclipse way of thinking, that’s kind of what I’m looking for. There I can split my project up into multiple modules and have Eclipse worry about resolving my dependencies in the workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way for this to magically work that I know of, however there are several alternatives that can ease your pain - use maven plugin for play:

**maven-play2-plugin**

http://nanoko-project.github.io/maven-play2-plugin/maven/release/

This one takes your dependencies and copies them into lib directory, where play picks them up. Still uses sbt to build play part of your application - that is the main disadvantage, you need to maintain 2 builds.

You still need to build your dependencies and then copy them to lib (using [copy-dependencies](http://nanoko-project.github.io/maven-play2-plugin/maven/release/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) command), but your IDE sees everything immediately.

**play2-maven-plugin**

https://code.google.com/p/play2-maven-plugin/

Everything is built by maven, but doesn't support play auto-reloading - you need to build & restart whole play project every time you make a change, which is kind of back to square one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Quick question; if convert the maven projects to sbt, would that solve the problem? Or how do people generally handle multi-module projects in Play Framework?

Comment: I think that for play to be able to pick up changes during auto-reload other modules must be submodules of your main project: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SBTSubProjects. Otherwise external sbt modules would behave the same as maven modules.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thanks for your help.